# How to hide alt text using CSS when the image is not present?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to hide the alt text using CSS in all the browsers,

I tried with `color:transparent`, it is working in all browsers except IE.

Is it possible to do it in IE using CSS?. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's the point of having alt text if you don't display it with the image can't be shown?

Comment: you can use `text-indent: -9999px;`

Comment: @Quentin: need for SEO and handled the image failure scenario in alternate way, showing default image

Comment: If the text isn't good enough for humans then it isn't good enough for search engines.

Comment: @FrayneKonok: Text-indent not working in IE9, 10

Comment: @MohamedHussain, say it to #Gaurav Aggarwal.

Comment: @Quentin: see this link http://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/  , here how they avoided the broken image default style using css styles , I am trying to achieve the same, for that I need to hide the default alt text from the browser

Comment: I think if you got here, maybe you should consider loading img contents using another 'method'. I mean server side ...

Comment: My pictures have a `<caption>` and the `alt` text is mainly provided for text to speech browsers. I show a loading image as the `<image>` `background-image` and the `alt` text interferes with this. Thankfully setting `img {color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` hides it - hopefully without hiding it from text to speech browsers.

Answer (score 20):

How about using `font-size: 0`? It works in hiding `alt` text before image loads or if image `src` URL is not available.

Comment: Works great for may lazy loaded images. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

The kellum method:

```
.hide-text {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also don't have the performance drawback of `-9999px` method where browser draw a box with size of 9999px.

Further explanation: [replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `text-indent:-9999px`

**HTML**

```
<img src="images/test.jpg" alt="alternative">
```

**CSS**

```
img{
  text-indent:-9999px
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/arq1Lcq3/)

Comment: if we add `line-height` then `text-indent` will work in all browsers...its better to use `line-height:1em;`

Comment: using `text-indent: -9999px` will make browser draws unnecessary 9999 empty space. Use the [kellum method](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `onerror` callback to set the display property to none:

```
<img src="images/test.txt" onerror="this.style.display='none';">
```

Comment: I was already wondering why nobody was including the error part in their anwser.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `color:transparent;` use `display:none;`.

But you **should not use** this technique.

As @Quentin said in the comment:

> If the text isn't good enough for humans then it isn't good enough for search engines.

You should not hide the alt text. Google knows this only used for SEO purpose and nothing important and will penalize for such. And you may be blacklisted on Google Search Engine.

So, don't use them just for SEO purpose.

Comment: thanks @Bhijendra Nepal Color is having the value transparent see the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent. Display :none won't solve my purpose

Comment: Sorry, I was presuming that.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: happen to all sometimes including me, no issues thanks for help

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: Thanks again for your edit in the answer, I like to hide the alt text which is coming as default from the browser unstyled , but nowhere i mentioned, i hidden it from the user i.e., I could use pseudo selector using content: attr(alt) and I like to avoid FOUC eventually.

Comment: any reason for downvote and unaccepted for this answer?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me. Just add it to your `img` styles:

```
text-indent: -100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-indent: -9999px;` and `display: none`.

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/29z1xwdb/)

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="technique-four">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="images/header-image.jpg" alt="CSS-Tricks" />
  </a>
</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1.technique-four {
    width: 350px; height: 75px;
    background: url("images/header-image.jpg");
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```css
img {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<img src="example.jpg" alt="text you don't want to show for those who can see, but make it visible for screen readers" />
```

`transparent` neither worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a best solution:

```
img {
  text-indent: -100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

An empty image is centered and alt text is not displayed. Also it does not overflow over other images.