# Hide image on 404 code, still shows broken image for few ms

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, src

This is my code:

```
<img ng-show="json.user.picture" ng-src="{{json.user.picture}}" ng-error="json.user.picture = false">
```

When the you dont have the permission to use the image from an external website you get a 404 code and when that happens I don't want to show the image. I'm doing that with the code above and it works but it still shows the broken image for a few ms how can you get rid of that?

Between ng-show en ng-hide there is a small delay which shows the broken image, how to get rid of that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide alt text using CSS when the image is not present?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305805/how-to-hide-alt-text-using-css-when-the-image-is-not-present)

Comment: Are you sure that the `ng-show` works at all? How are you fetching the image? Is the URL for the image fetched in a promise call? It is quite possible that the hiding never works, and the delay you mentioned is simply the image been fetched (broken or otherwise)

Comment: It's not a duplicate I'm not trying to get rid of the text but the broken image itself. And yes ng-show works and the hiding also works it's just that there is a small delay in between that shows a broken image that I want to get rid off

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is; you are using `json.user.picture` as the condition to show image as well as the source of the image. so if `ng-error` triggers it will change `json.user.picture` to `false` so the image source become `false` and it tries to load the image with name `false` like `<img src='false'>` which will again throw an error.

So you have to use an extra variable like `showImage` which will be `true` by default. on error change this to `false` and use it in `ng-show`

so it will be like

`<img ng-show="showImage" ng-src="{{json.user.picture}}" ng-error="showImage = false">`